# How to access all android emulator storage by android studios device file explorer?

Tags: android, filesystems, emulation

For testing reasons I used to save generated images on an emulator and get them by pulling the files from the emulator Android Studio offers. But since Arctic Fox it seems I cannot access all files on the emulator anymore.

The image below shows a red line of text where all the installed packages should be. How is it possible to access internal storage?

[image: Device File Explorer]

The code I use for image saving is this:

```
object BitmapExporter {

    private const val constructReferenceIcons = true

    const val exportReferenceDpi = 480
    const val defaultDrawableDpi = 160

    private fun saveBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, filename: String, context: Context) {
        val filePath: String = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/DEBUG_IMAGES"

        val dir = File(filePath)
        if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs()
        val file = File(dir, "$filename.png")
        val fOut = FileOutputStream(file)

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut)
        fOut.flush()
        fOut.close()
    }

    fun saveBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, resourceId: Int, context: Context) {
        @Suppress("ConstantConditionIf")
        if (constructReferenceIcons) {
            saveBitmap(bitmap, context.resources.getResourceEntryName(resourceId), context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange. Here all packages are shown and accessable.

Comment: Is your emulator running? It should.

Comment: I must say that on an Android 10 device i get the same red text and Permission deniet if you enlarge column.

Comment: Try /storage/self/primary/Android. And there are more paths that lead to 'data' try them all.

Comment: Similar red text on /storage/self/primary/Android

Comment: Save the generated images to another place that you can reach.

Comment: Well it works if I use API26.